# Unable to set the correct position for a rectangle in LIBGDX

Tags: libgdx, position, rectangles

I want to draw a rectangle but I am not able to set the position of a rectangle in the way I wanted. I tried adjusting many values but nothing helped. 
  This is my code,

```
    Body b2body;
    Rectangle rectangle;
    BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    b2body = screens.getWorld().createBody(bdef);
    rectangle = new Rectangle();
    rectangle.setHeight(55);
    rectangle.setWidth(55);
    PolygonShape head = new PolygonShape();
    rectangle.setX(1200);
    rectangle.setY(10);
    bdef.position.set((rectangle.getX() - rectangle.getWidth() / 2) / MyJungleGame.PPM, (rectangle.getY() - rectangle.getHeight() / 2) / MyJungleGame.PPM);
    head.setAsBox(rectangle.getWidth() / 2 / MyJungleGame.PPM, rectangle.getHeight() / 2 / MyJungleGame.PPM);
    FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
    fdef.shape = head;
```

My output screen looks like,

[image: output]

I am trying to adjust the small rectangle's position. I tried changing the x and y values but nothing helps. I am a newbie in LIBGDX. Please help. !!

Comment: Where does the rectangle need to be in b relation to the world? On my phone now but so can't really help but it's useful information.

Comment: Anywhere in the bottom of the world. I just want the solution to adjust its position @MennoGouw

Comment: so if you do `shapeRenderer.rect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, rectangle.width, rectangle.height);` it not drawing in the correct position? Either somewhere you change the rect or you lack understanding of the world, camera and screen view.

Comment: To adjust the position of a rectangle you just set it's X and Y. But as I look in your code you want to represent the rectangle with the box2d body. Mind though, the `ShapeRenderer` uses libgdx coordinate system where Y points up. And in box2d Y points down.

Comment: Yes I just want to check if the rectangle is touched. Here is my link to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35823096/unable-to-detect-if-a-rectangle-is-touched-in-libgdx/35826990#35826990 any help would be appreciated @MennoGouw

Answer (score 0):

Just tell me where do you want to draw the rectangle ,are you looking for the collision detection between two sprites ?, just comment it in detail i can surely help you